# R - How to have comparative and superlative suffixes count as the same stem word

Tags: r, statistics, nlp, tm

When I generate DocumentTermMatrix or TermDocumentMatrix objects and enable their Stemwords feature, it doesn't count comparative nor superlative suffixed words as the same word. Heavier, heaviest are not heavy.

Here's my example:

```
library(RTextTools)
library(topicmodels)
library(tm)

data <- c("I'm having trouble with superlative and comparative suffixes", 
             "Heaviest.",
            "this is heavy heavier.")

matrix <- create_matrix(data, language="english", toLower = TRUE, removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=TRUE, removePunctuation = TRUE, removeStopwords = TRUE, weighting=weightTf)
inspect(matrix)
colnames(matrix)
```

Here's the output:

```
>.....
Terms
Docs compar heavi heavier heaviest suffix superl troubl
   1      1     0       0        0      1      1      1
   2      0     0       0        1      0      0      0
   3      0     1       1        0      0      0      0

> colnames(matrix) 
[1] "compar"   "heavi"    "heavier"  "heaviest" "suffix"   "superl"   "troubl"
```

The ideal output I am looking for is not only that "heavier" and "heaviest" are the same as "heavi", but that "Heavi" shows up once in the 2nd document, and twice in the last document.

I have tried enabling and disabling the stemwords, removeStopwords, min/maxwordlength flags. The Min/Maxwordlengths worked for bigger words, but it still did not count "heaviest" as "heavi" in the term matrix. The stemming that rTextTools seems to use Porter's algorithm. (Reference: http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/RTextTools/docs/create_matrix)

I would like to ideally generate a DocumentTermMatrix in the end, so I have been working on manipulating the matrix and trying what kind of pre-processing I could do on the data itself. But no luck thus far.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Might the package qdap apply a different stemming algorithm?  It integrates pretty well with tm.  Second idea: perhaps a lemmatization function would help?

Comment: I tried applying qdap, but it still counted the superlatives differently. Lemmatization functions would work in theory. In my search though, the examples I have found only hand-coded the substitutions, and then suggested stemming. Wordnet seems to be close, but I did not find directly applicable examples in its documentation.

Comment: Two other ideas: write Tyler Rinker, the maintainer of qdap, and ask him to look at your question.  Second, perhaps a regex like str_replace with the pattern being along the lines of "ier$ & iest$" would str_replace the most common comparative endings.  Problems lurk there also.  Then there are other people who use Python and a package called something like NLTK.